# Gradle Plugin 3.2.0 with databinding, can not resolve package name

Tags: android, gradle, android-databinding

After updating Android Studio from 3.1.2 to 3.2.0, and updating the gradle plugin with it to 3.2.0, I am having a problem with a generated databinding classes which are complaining about a package name that does not exist, but it does exist. The package belongs to a module in the project.

Here are the errors that I am getting when trying to run the app:

> error: cannot find symbol class Helper
>
> error: package Helper does not exist

This is my project level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is the `build.gradle` for the module which having the problem:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

I tried all sort of things:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the project
- Invalidating caches and restarting
- Cleaning gradle and gradle cache
- Updating Gradle to the latest version
- Changing the module name and the used package name in it

None did work.

EDIT: added screenshot[image]

Comment: Is there any `Helper` class in your project? If yes, go to the class and see if imports has issues or not. **Checking the logs** will show you where the class is or has issue. However, how about adding screenshot of the error with more information?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท there is no `Helper` class in my project, it is a package name. The package does exist, but databinding can't find it. I added a screenshot

Comment: try to use gradle 3.1.3, because probably the version 3.2.0 has errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the SAME ISSUE today.

The problem is your package name itself. You mentioned:

> there is no Helper class in my project, it is a package name. The package does exist, but databinding can't find it.

**Short Answer:**

Change your package name that starts with a lower case letter. The problem happens because your package name is `Helper`. Change it to `helper`.

**Long Answer:**

In Android Plugin 3.2.0 and above, the databinding V2 is enabled by default.
I guess the databinding V2 compiler treats any component that starts with an upper case letter as a class, not a package. It is actually looking for a class with a name `Helper`, not the package `Helper`.

Because you were using Android 3.1.2 before, which is using the databinding V1 compiler, the package name wasn't an issue.

I renamed all my package(folder) names in my project to start with a lower case letter and the project was finally compiled. Make sure to use the refactor tool `(Shift + F6)` when you rename the packages so that the change can be applied to your XML files also!!

**BONUS:**

Just in case you want to keep the package names to start with upper case letters, but also want to use the Android Plugin 3.2.0 (which is not really recommended), go to gradle.properties in the root folder and add this line. This disables the databindingV2 compiler and forces the project to use the old V1 compiler. Therefore your class name won't matter.

> android.databinding.enableV2=false

But why would anyone want to do this? :/

Comment: Excellent! Thank you :)

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 Glad to help you :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe the reason the Uppercase folder name breaks the build is because for some reason when the binding classes are generated it Sees the Capital Folder name as the class and the actual file you want as a subclass. Not sure why It does this but that's what it looks like

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Highcharts library (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android) and I found the same problem with databinding - import after updating the gradle plugin to 3.2.0.

This version has probably errors included, so stay with the version 3.1.3.

The databinding file in version 3.2.0 :

[import error in gradle 3.2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1oGl.jpg)

The databinding file in version 3.1.3:

[import OK in gradle 3.1.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuCym.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In your codes, it's actually using `EmojiIconEdittext` helper class which comes from [supernova library](https://github.com/hani-momanii/SuperNova-Emoji) but in your dependencies, **there is no such dependency added in there.**

So, add this to your `Build.gradle` dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'
```

Or remove the class (*If you don't wanna use it*) and then it will work fine.

<sub>**P.S**: The import actually tells the truth.</sub>

```
import supernova.emoji.helper
```

Comment: Yes I am using that library, but I had to import it locally (as a module) because I needed to make some changes to it to meet my needs. And I can not remove because obviously I need it.

Comment: I couldn't see how you import it into your project, at least there were no codes related inside your `Build.gradle`. Probably `compile files('libs/library.jar')` missed in your `Build.gradle`? Also, remove the current import and see if it suggest the right import or not.

Comment: that's the project level gradle file, I did not include to app level gradle, here is the line that imports the library locally : `implementation project(':supernova-emoji-library')`

Comment: If you remove the import (`import supernova.emoji.helper`), will be any suggested imports in there? If not, the library you have imported to your project cannot be resolved.

Comment: If I remove it, I get the right suggestion for the right imports, and the error disappears, in the editor anyway, but those are generated code for databinding (I did not write it), and when I run the project again, those classes get generated again and the errors reappear.

Comment: Then that's the library issue I suppose which needs to be checked. However, `but those are generated code for databinding (I did not write it)` Please add more screenshot of what you have tried and what it suggested(as imports) to the question in order to help you more.