# DataBinding Error in Gradle Build- Android Gradle 3.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Currently i am trying to upgrade my project into the android x but before that i was done the gradle wrapper 4.10.1 and `tools.build:gradle:3.2.0` but i am getting the following error and all my code in java only.

Anybody knows how will resolve these kind of issues.

```
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesProjectMDebug

> Task :app:compileProjectMDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
E:\SVN\Hindi_v_28_Final_AndroidX\BM-6.3_v28\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\ProjectMDebug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesProjectMDebug\out\com\ProjectMs\databinding\ActivityAddDetailPopupBinding.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
import com.ProjectMs.viewmodel.AddDetail;
                                    ^
  symbol:   class AddDetail
  location: package com.ProjectMs.viewmodel
E:\SVN\Hindi_v_28_Final_AndroidX\BM-6.3_v28\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\ProjectMDebug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesProjectMDebug\out\com\ProjectMs\databinding\ActivityAddDetailPopupBinding.java:129: error: package AddDetail does not exist
  protected AddDetail.AddDetailViewModel mViewModel;
                     ^
E:\SVN\Hindi_v_28_Final_AndroidX\BM-6.3_v28\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\ProjectMDebug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesProjectMDebug\out\com\ProjectMs\databinding\ActivityAddDetailPopupBinding.java:183: error: package AddDetail does not exist
  public abstract void setViewModel(@Nullable AddDetail.AddDetailViewModel viewModel);
```

Comment: Did you get a solution? I updated to AS 3.3 and started getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Plugin 3.2.0 and above, the databinding V2 is enabled by default. I guess the databinding V2 compiler treats any component that starts with an upper case letter as a class, not a package

After change the lower case its works well like "adddetail" instead of "AddDetail".
import com.ProjectMs.viewmodel.adddetail;

Thanks. Refer url 
[Gradle Plugin 3.2.0 with databinding, can not resolve package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52495124/gradle-plugin-3-2-0-with-databinding-can-not-resolve-package-name)